# When publishing can I replace "link:../dir" with the version of the package being linked with?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

In my package.json I have

```
"dependencies": {
  "components": "link:../components",
  "react": "^16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
}
```

This works fine during development, however when trying to publish the packages to npm the "link:../components" is published into the package.

Is there a way to take the "link:../components" and replace it with the version of the package.json in the file it's being linked with?

basically

```
"dependencies": {
  "components": "link:../components",
  "react": "^16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
}
```

would convert to

```
"dependencies": {
  "components": "1.2.3",
  "react": "^16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
}
```

before being published to npm. The linked dependency would remain locally, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm link` is a development utility to test your npm packages before you publish them.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Using your example names, say you are developing a npm package `components`. While you are developing it, you want to test it in your main project (The consumer of your package).
The way to go about this is, to go in your `components` package dir, and run `npm link`, this will create a global link in your system that will make it available to other projects.

So now you can go in your main project dir, and run `npm link components` (`components` is the name of your package, not to be confused with dir name)

This is fine during development, but of course won't work when you publish your packages.

> Is there a way to take the "link:../components" and replace it with the version of >the package.json in the file it's being linked with?

- First publish `components` package to npm (A good
  [article](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tiny-npm-package-and-publish-it-2881d4307f78)
  that explains it)
- In your main project dir, run `npm unlink
  components`.
  This will remove the global link to `components` in your 
  project dir.
- In your main project dir, run `npm install components`.
  This will fetch `components` from npm.

Comment: Do I have to maintain the linked version numbers? So if my consumer has version `1.0.0` in the package.json and the local linked version is `2.0.0`. Will I need to manually update the consumer version to remain in sync?

Comment: No you don't, since your package is not published, you don't have version numbers. Make sure to run npm link in your component every time you update it.

Comment: @David If my answer worked for you, I'd appreciate you marking it as the accepted answer :)